# How can I set the background color in CSS by receiving the color value dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following code:

```
<style>
    .color-3 {
    background-color: <%= this.BckColor %>;
    }
</style>
```

to receive a value from a C# page. My C# code receives a background image color from a page called 'settings' page, and the C# code is:

```
 string BckColor ="#" + Convert.ToString((Settings["DOTCOLOR"]));
```

but when I do this, the background color is missing. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please make an effort to create proper Markdown content. Your question was unreadable. It's not complex, and there is a bunch of help content (click on the orange `?` to get help).

Comment: Are you sure that there is a `DOTCOLOR` key in your `web.config`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use this :

```
<style>
    .color-3 {
    background-color: #<%= Convert.ToString(Settings["DOTCOLOR"]) %>;

}
</style>
```

Or create a property in your page class:

```
public string BgColor{
    get { return Convert.ToString(Settings["DOTCOLOR"]); }
}
```

and

```
<style>
    .color-3 {
    background-color: #<%= BgColor%>;

}
</style>
```